# Installing wordpress multisite nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx, magento2, multisite

I have been trying to integrate wordpress multisite on magento using this extension
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/

It works fine for single site, but for multisite when I try to enable multisite it will poping out this error:-
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVXXd.jpg)

I have installed wordpress inside magento, here are the paths:

`/var/www/html2/` <---- Magento 2

`/var/www/html2/wp/` <---- Wordpress

I suspect the nginx could be the issue, but I'm new to nginx, here is my configuration for nginx (`/etc/nginx/sites-available/dbr`):-

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name dbr.test.net www.dbr.test.net;
        set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html2;
        set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    #    include /vagrant/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;

    #root $MAGE_ROOT;
    root $MAGE_ROOT/pub; index index.php; autoindex off; charset off;
    add_header 'X-Content-Type-Options' 'nosniff'; add_header
    'X-XSS-Protection' '1; mode=block';
    location ~ (wp) {
            root $MAGE_ROOT;
        index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /usr/share/nginx/html$fastcgi_script_name;

                try_files $uri $uri/ /wp/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite_log on;
        rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) /wp$1 last;
    rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ /wp$1 last;

        # rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
        # rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
    }

        location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico|svg)$ {
                   expires max;
                 log_not_found off;
         }

    }

    location /setup {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;
        location ~ ^/setup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

        location ~ ^/themesetup/index.php {
            fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
        $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~ ^/setup/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/setup/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }
    location /update {
        root $MAGE_ROOT;
        location ~ ^/update/index.php {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/update/index.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        # deny everything but index.php
        location ~ ^/update/(?!pub/). {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/update/pub/ {
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
        }
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location /pub {
        location ~
    ^/pub/media/(downloadable|customer|import|theme_customization/.*\.xml) {
            deny all;
        }
        alias $MAGE_ROOT/pub;
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
    location /static/ {
        if ($MAGE_MODE = "production") {
            expires max;
        }
        location ~ ^/static/version{
          rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static/$2 last;
        }
        location ~* \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";

            expires +1y;
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
                rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
                expires off;
            if (!-f $request_filename) {
               rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
            }
        }
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/static/(version\d*/)?(.*)$ /static.php?resource=$2 last;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
    location /media/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        location ~ ^/media/theme_customization/.*\.xml {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~*
    \.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg|js|css|swf|eot|ttf|otf|woff|woff2)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires +1y;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        location ~* \.(zip|gz|gzip|bz2|csv|xml)$ {
            add_header Cache-Control "no-store";
            add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
            expires off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /get.php?$args;
        }
        add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    }
    location /media/customer/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location /media/downloadable/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location /media/import/ {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ cron\.php {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ (index|get|static|report|404|503)\.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        #auth_basic "Restricted Content"; auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
        fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
        fastcgi_param PHP_FLAG "session.auto_start=off \n
    suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
        fastcgi_param PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=1G \n
    max_execution_time=5900";
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1800s;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 1800s;
        fastcgi_param MAGE_MODE $MAGE_MODE;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
    rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}   
    location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

    expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    #fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
    #fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
    include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a WordPress misconfiguration (?). Is this how you enabled multisite?

1. `define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );`
2. **Administration** > **Tools** > **Network Setup**
3. Add lines to `wp-config.php` as instructed.